# Custom XML binding causes word doc to lose content control style/font

Tags: xml, data-binding, ms-word

I am trying to do a word document that has content control bindings to an XML document that I am swapping out for custom.xml in the word docx package.

When I created my original document, I added fonts and size and style to the content control text. This made it fit the rest of my documents style.

Then when I swap in the custom XML content, and re-open the document, all of the style stuff is gone and it is showing up as a Calibri font size 10 - nothing like the arial size 18 bold I specified.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this Word 2010 or 2007. I seem to recall XML content controls being removed as a result of a lawsuit with Microsoft, so that might not be a good strategy moving forward.

Comment: It is Word 2010. I am not sure that lawsuit pertained to this - do you have a link? I thought injecting your own custom XML was the only way to dynamically bind data to a content control in Word

Comment: Here's one http://tech.icrontic.com/news/microsoft-loses-word-xml-lawsuit-strips-feature/   .... Just google word xml content lawsuit for tons of articles. Still hard to say whether what you're doing would be impacted but I'd definitely check. I'm working on a Word Mail Merge extension and was originally going to use XML content stuff, but had to back out and go with plain only Word Mail merge fields because they're safer.